# Set= log.txt in batch

Tags: batch-file, set, logging, text-files

I have like a log.txt file which contains:

```
MyName
```

My batch:

```
@echo off
set name= [log.txt]
```

in the [log.txt] part, it should read 'MyName' from the log.txt file, to set it as 'name'.

How?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also use

```
set /p name=<log.txt
```

which might be considered shorter and a little less ugly.

Comment: Dunno :-). Both methods work actually, but have different effects with files containing more than just one line.

Comment: Nice.  We don't get to be able to feed stdin with files very often with cmd compared to bash, I'll remember this one.

Answer (score 2):

In cmd.exe, there's only this ugly way:

```
@echo off
for /f "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%i in ("log.txt") do (
    set name=%%i
)
```

Comment: You can cut the usebackq and tokens options from there, by the way, as you're not using them.

Comment: @Joey `tokens=* delims=` is faster as a single `delims=`

Comment: @Joey: if you parse long lines, the `tokens=* delims=` variant takes only ~70% of the time

Comment: @jeb: I just tested but was unable to discern a significant time difference. What exactly is a long line for you?

Comment: @Joey: I tested it with a line length of 7000 characters, the discussion is at [tokens and delims](https://groups.google.com/group/alt.msdos.batch.nt/browse_thread/thread/74cbae5137f1a73b#)