# How to get an EC2 Windows machine's instance-id into a batch variable

Tags: windows, batch-file, amazon-ec2

I have a batch file that I'd like to run on startup of an EC2 Windows AMI.  The program I'd like to run from that batch file takes the instance-id of the EC2 machine as a parameter.  What is the simplest way to get that Instance ID passed as an argument to that program?

From [Amazon's Documentation on the subject](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/2008-08-08/DeveloperGuide/index.html?AESDG-chapter-instancedata.html), I see that you're supposed to issue a WGET to a specified URL and parse the response.  So an alternate way of phrasing this question might be "How do I pass the contents of a HTTP request to a program as an argument in a Windows batch file"

In pseudocode, this is what I'd like to do:

```
set ID = GET http://169.254.169.254/2008-08-08/meta-data/instance-id
myprogram.exe /instanceID=%ID%
```

Any suggestions on how I might proceed?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot open URLs directly in a batch file. You can certainly use wget or similar to retrieve the contents of that URL. Then you either get a file (whose contents you can assign to an environment variable [see for example [Set= log.txt in batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932552/set-log-txt-in-batch)]) or you'll get output from the program in which case you can wrap it into

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%x in (`print_contents_of_url http://169.254.169.254/2008-08-08/meta-data/instance-id`) do set ID=%%x
```

which would set `%ID%` to the server response at that URL [assuming that the program does what I named it]).

In both cases you'll need a separate program to speak HTTP, though.

Comment: That makes sense.  So wget>file.txt, then set /p name=<log.txt.  Thanks!

Comment: You can't just pipe wget's output. But wget will write what it gets to a file with the -O option, so you should use wget -O file.txt http://...